# Google Cloud Platform CentOS7 Apache Config and/or Filesystem Permissions

Tags: php, centos7, google-cloud-platform

Porting a web application written in PHP from private hosting server (CentOS6) to Google Cloud Platform CentOS7 VM.  Having file and filesystem permission problems.  Can execute PHP scripts generating dynamic page content (fed by MariaDB) without issue.

Problem: Cannot rename/move/copy via native PHP executed from web server.

Following script (test.php) works if executed from command line as owning user:

```
<?php
  chmod('test_file.pdf', 0755);
  rename ('test_file.pdf','test_file.pdf2');
?>
```

Does not work from apache (running by invoking URL in browser - site.com/test.php).

*Warning: rename(test_file.pdf,test_file.pdf2): Permission denied in test.php on line 3*

Permissions for HTML_DOC_ROOT directory is set to 777.  Permissions on test_file.pdf set to 777.

Am I missing some newer Apache directive controlling access to web site directory tree or files in general?

Comment: There might be some SELinux happening or the apache user does not have access to modify the file permissions. The rename should work. Can you test the rename only and can you verify if selinux is installed and running.

Comment: ANSWER - Yes, had to disable SELinux in /etc/sysconfig/selinux.  Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, that has caused me some issues too in the past.